# what is "fermés algébriques/fermés irréductibles"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I cant understand what is meant by "fermés algébriques/fermés irréductibles" in the following corollary:

Si $S \subseteq k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$, on note $V(S):= \{x \in A^n: \forall f \in S, f(x) = 0\}$.

Si $Z \subseteq A^n(k)$, on pose $I(Z):= \{f \in k[T_1, \cdots, T_n]: f|_Z = 0\}$.

Corollaire 1.1.6.1 Les applications: $\{\text{idéaux radicaux de } k[T]\} \longleftrightarrow \{\text{fermés algébriques de } A^n\}$, $I \longrightarrow V(I)$, $I(Z) \longleftarrow Z$ sont des bijections réciproques. Les restrictions donnent des bijections réciproques:
$\{\text{idéaux maximaux de } k[T]\}  \longleftrightarrow  \{\text{points de } A^n\}$. Par cette bijection, les idéaux premiers correspondent aux fermés irréductibles.

Translation:

If $S \subseteq k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$, we note $V(S):= \{x \in A^n: \forall f \in S, f(x) = 0\}$.

If $Z \subseteq A^n(k)$, we set $I(Z):= \{f \in k[T_1, \cdots, T_n]: f|_Z = 0\}$.

Corollaire 1.1.6.1 Applications: $\{\text{ideals radicals of } k[T]\} \longleftrightarrow \{\text{fermés algébriques de } A^n\}$, $I \longrightarrow V(I)$, $I(Z) \longleftarrow Z$ are reciprocal bijections. Restrictions provide reciprocal bijections:
$\{\text{maximal ideals of } k[T]\}  \longleftrightarrow  \{\text{points of } A^n\}$. By this bijection, the prime ideals correspond to fermés irréductibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fermé = closed, algébrique = algebraic, thus fermé algébrique is an algebraic i.e. closed subset with respect to the Zariski topology. And irréductible = irreducible. You could have also looked at *any* text on algebraic geometry in English ...